# ng-show odd behaviour What's going on?

Tags: angularjs

I have some weird behaviour going on with ng-show. I have a `post`, with `title` and `link` properties. Link  may or may not exist. If it does, I want to show the title as a link, else just the title.

(The line:`<a href="{{post.link}}"> {{post.link}}</a>` is test code, and is only there to illustrate that `{{post.link}}` does, in fact, definitely contain a value.)

```
  <a ng-show="{{post.link}}" href="{{post.link}}">
            {{post.title}}
   </a>

   <a href="{{post.link}}"> {{post.link}}</a>
```

Gives me:

[image]

So, you can seem that `{{post.link}}` exists, is accessible and is populated ... but is still somehow evaluating to false as far as ng-show is concerned, and is not showing up. All I can see is the result of the test code.

Whereas, if I evaluate `true`, or even `{{post.title}}`, then the ng-show works.

I am baffled - what have I missed?

```
 <a ng-show="true" href="{{post.link}}">
        {{post.title}}
 </a>
 <a href="{{post.link}}"> {{post.link}}</a>
```

or

```
 <a ng-show="{{post.title}}" href="{{post.link}}">
        {{post.title}}
 </a>
 <a href="{{post.link}}"> {{post.link}}</a>
```

Gives me:

[image]

Comment: as well as below, use ng-href see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ng-show doesn't need `{{ ... }}` as it uses variables directly. Change it to

```
ng-show="post.link"
```

`{{ ... }}` is only used when you want the output to be visible in the dom. ng-show is angular so you don't need it.